# join function of a numpy array composed of string

Tags: python, arrays, string, join, numpy

I'm trying to use the `join` function on a numpy array composed of only strings (representing binary floats) to get the joined string in order to use the `numpy.fromstring` function, but the `join` function doesn't seem to work properly.

Any idea why? Which alternative function can I use to do that?

Here is a standalone example to show my problem:

```
import numpy as np

nb_el = 10

table = np.arange(nb_el, dtype='float64')
print table

binary = table.tostring()

binary_list = map(''.join, zip(*[iter(binary)] * table.dtype.itemsize))
print 'len binary list :', len(binary_list)
# len binary list : 10

join_binary_list = ''.join(binary_list)
print np.fromstring(join_binary_list, dtype='float64')
# [ 0.  1.  2.  3.  4.  5.  6.  7.  8.  9.]

binary_split_array = np.array(binary_list)
print 'nb el :', binary_split_array.shape
# nb el : (10,)
print 'nb_el * size :', binary_split_array.shape[0] * binary_split_array.dtype.itemsize
# nb_el * size : 80

join_binary_split_array = ''.join(binary_split_array)
print 'len binary array :', len(join_binary_split_array)
# len binary array : 72

table_fromstring = np.fromstring(join_binary_split_array, dtype='float64')
print table_fromstring
# [ 1.  2.  3.  4.  5.  6.  7.  8.  9.]
```

As you can see, using the join function on the list (`binary_list`) works properly, but on the equivalent numpy array (`binary_split_array`) it doesn't: we can see the string returned is only 72 characters long instead of 80.

Comment: I found an alternative way (I should know how to use the search bar by now... ) to join using the `tostring()` function. But any idea on why `join` doesn't work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first element of your `join_binary_split_array` is an empty string:

```
print(repr(binary_split_array[0]))    
''
```

The first element in your list is:

```
'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

An empty string has a length of 0:

```
print([len("".join(a)) for a in binary_split_array])
print([len("".join(a)) for a in binary_list])
[0, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8]
[8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8]
```

The length of the str of bytes  8:

```
print(len('\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'))
8
```

Calling tobytes  will give the same output length as the list:

```
print(len(binary_split_array.tobytes()))
80

table_fromstring = np.fromstring(binary_split_array.tobytes(), dtype='float64')

print table_fromstring
[ 0.  1.  2.  3.  4.  5.  6.  7.  8.  9.]
```

The numpy array [handles](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/2414) null bytes differently to python, null bytes are truncated.

Comment: that is funny... if you do the exact same thing but with `table` not containing the value `0.` it works! that means that the `numpy.array()` function treats differently the string `'0.00'` and `'1.00'` or am I not understanding correctly?

Comment: Seems that way doing  `binary = table.tostring() + "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"` exhibits the same behaviour. You can put  `x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"` anywhere in the string and it will do the same